# Scope of Linux Environment Variables

Tags: linux, scope, environment-variables, echo

Can someone explain the difference in scope of environment variables in the following 4 examples?

```
❯❯❯ b=1 echo $b

❯❯❯ b=1; echo $b
1
❯❯❯ 
❯❯❯ cat gen.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo $a
❯❯❯ 
❯❯❯ a=1 ./gen.sh
1
❯❯❯ a=1; ./gen.sh
```

Comment: Reading https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/104 will help.

Answer (score 2):

1. Expansion of $parameters is done before executing a command, using the current environment.
2. Assigning a parameter does not automatically *export* it to child processes (commands), but only on subsequent *invocations* of commands (in their command line, as per rule #1).
3. But, a command in the form "a=b command" has an assignment that is exported to the command, but only temporarily - only for that single command invocation.

Given the three rules above:

> ❯❯❯ b=1 echo $b

gets first translated to: b=1 echo ""
... and prints nothing.

> ❯❯❯ b=1; echo $b

works, because there are two distinct commands, as if they were put on two different lines. The first is expanded and sets a variable; then the second is expanded.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $a
```

(this script prints the $a found in the environment).

> ❯❯❯ a=1 ./gen.sh

This works because a=1 is exported, so gen.sh founds it in the environment.

> ❯❯❯ a=1; ./gen.sh

This does not work because a=1 is set but not exported to child processes; so gen.sh starts but does not find $a in the environment. The following instead would work:

❯❯❯ export a=1; ./gen.sh